# Changing Table Format

Tags: tables

Is there someone who is able to replicate a table in this format:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show us what you have tried?!

Comment: There is a package for tables called booktabs. Information about booktabs can be found at https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs?lang=en This package has excellent documentation. If you have problems iinstalling or using this package, display what you have tried.

Comment: in addition to Jay's comment: You might want to take a look into the `threeparttable` package (for tablenotes)  and the `colortbl` (\usepackage[table]{xcolor})  package (for alternatingly colored row in tables).

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I was primarily interested in the packages that can be employed. To be honest, I tried a little bit but got stuck. So, I will give it a try tomorrow once again and post it if it doesn't work with the suggested packages.

Comment: This table should be transposed, so that anyone looking at it can quickly see which condition is larger than another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution will help you understand how to use different packages and achieve the table that you have attached as screenshot. You can further enhance it according to your requirements.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{table}
\begin{adjustbox}{width=1\textwidth}
    \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{\textbf{Hospital admissions for five chronic conditions, EU countries, 2015}}
        \begin{tabular}{l r r r r r r}
            \toprule
            & \centering Diabetes & \centering Hypertension & \centering Heart failure & \multicolumn{1}{p{3cm}}{\centering COPD and \\ Bronchiectasis} & \centering Asthma & \multicolumn{1}{p{3cm}}{\centering \textbf{Total(five conditions)}} \\
            \midrule
            \rowcolor{blue!5} Admissions/discharges & $800 303$ & $655 396$ & $1 749 384$ & $1 109 865$ & $328 976$ & \boldmath $4 653 924$ \\
            $\%$ of all admissions & $1.0\%$ & $0.8\%$ & $2.1\%$ & $1.3\%$ & $0.4\%$ & \boldmath $5.6\%$ \\
            \rowcolor{blue!5} Average LOS (days) & $8.5$ & $6.9$ & $9.5$ & $8.9$ & $6.6$ & \boldmath $8.1$ (avg.) \\
            Total bed days & $6 794 572$ & $4 597 886$ & $16 619 148$ & $9 855 601$ & $2 177 821$ & \boldmath $37 603 706$ \\
            \rowcolor{blue!5} Proportion of all bed days & $1.1\%$ & $0.7\%$ & $2.7\%$ & $1.6\%$ & $0.4\%$ & \boldmath $6.5\%$ \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \begin{tablenotes}
        \item[Note:] The data on hospital admissions refer to discharges (including deaths in hospital).
        \item[Source:] OECD Health Statistics
        \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{adjustbox}    
\end{table}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help. It looks really nice, and this is what I was looking for. Once again, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

with use [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/475804/changing-table-format/475932#475932) written by [subham soni](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/41885/subham-soni) as starting point:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{booktabs,cellspace, tabularx}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{2pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{2pt}
\addparagraphcolumntypes{X}
\newcommand\mcx[1]{\multicolumn{1}{@{} >{\centering\arraybackslash}X @{}}{#1}}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newrobustcmd{\B}{\fontseries{b}\selectfont}

\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]
    \begin{table}[htb]
    \footnotesize
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Hospital admissions for five chronic conditions, EU countries, 2015}
    \rowcolors{2}{white}{cyan!30}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{Cl *{6}{S[detect-weight, % <--
                                       mode=text,     % <--
                                       table-format=7.1]}
                            }
    \hline
    & \mcx{Diabetes}                & \mcx{Hypertension}    & \mcx{Heart failure}
    & \mcx{COPD and Bronchiectasis} & \mcx{Asthma}          & \mcx{\bfseries
                                                                Total (five conditions)} \\
    \hline
Admissions/discharges
    & 800 303   & 655396    & 1 749 384 & 1 109 865 & 328 976   & \B 4 653 924          \\
\% of all admissions
    & {1.0\%}   & {0.8\%}   & {2.1\%}   & {1.3\%}   & {0.4\%}   & {\textbf{5.6\%}}      \\
Average LOS (days)
    & 8.5       & 6.9       & 9.5       & 8.9       & 6.6       & \B 8.1                \\
Total bed days
    & 6 794 572 & 4 597 886 & 16619148  & 9855601   & 2177821   & \B 37603706           \\
Proportion of all bed days
    & {1.1\%}   & {0.7\%}   & {2.7\%}   & {1.6\%}   & {0.4\%}   & {\B 6.5\%}            \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]\scriptsize
\note   The data on hospital admissions refer to discharges (including deaths in hospital).
\source OECD Health Statistics \url{https://doi.org/10.1787/healt-data-en} Eurostat database \dots
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the effort. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also build this table using [cals](https://ctan.org/pkg/textpos). Some more coding, but full control. Unfortunately [cals](https://ctan.org/pkg/textpos) has no option for changing the colour of rules, so you may chose whatever colour you desire, *as long as it is black*:

```
\documentclass[british, DIV=12, captions=tableheading]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{cals, url}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[footnotefigures]{MinionPro}
\input{glyphtounicode}
\pdfgentounicode=1
\usepackage[scaled=0.86]{luximono}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}

\RequirePackage[letterspace=100,%
                babel=true,%
                tracking=true,%
                kerning=true]%
        {microtype}

\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{uop}
\let\nc=\nullcell                                                  % Shortcuts
\let\sc=\spancontent

\addtokomafont{caption}{\sffamily\bfseries\small}
\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\normalfont}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
\caption{Hospital admissions for five chronic conditions, \textls*{EU} countries, 2015}
\footnotesize\sffamily
\begin{calstable}[c]
% Defining columns relative to each other and relative to the margins
\colwidths{{\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/70*15+4pt\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/70*9-2pt\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/70*9+2pt\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/70*9\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/70*9+6pt\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/70*9-2pt\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/70*9\relax}
            }
% The tabular fills the text area if sum of all columns is 6

% Set up the tabular
\makeatletter
\def\cals@framers@width{0.8pt}   % Outside frame rules, reduce if the rule is too heavy
\def\cals@framecs@width{0pt}
\def\cals@bodyrs@width{0.6pt}
\def\cals@cs@width{0pt}             % Inside rules, reduce if the rule is too heavy
\def\cals@rs@width{0.6pt}
\def\cals@bgcolor{}

\def\tb{\ifx\cals@borderT\relax     % Top border switch (off-on)
    \def\cals@borderT{0pt}
\else \let\cals@borderT\relax\fi}

\def\bb{\ifx\cals@borderB\relax     % Botton border switch (off-on)
    \def\cals@borderB{0pt}
\else \let\cals@borderB\relax\fi}

\def\rb{\ifx\cals@borderR\relax     % Right border switch (off-on)
    \def\cals@borderR{0pt}
\else \let\cals@borderR\relax\fi}

\def\lp{\ifdim\cals@paddingL=0.0pt\relax    % Left padding switch (off-on)
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
\else \setlength{\cals@paddingL}{0pt}\fi}

\def\rp{\ifdim\cals@paddingR=0.0pt\relax    % Left padding switch (off-on)
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
\else \setlength{\cals@paddingR}{0pt}\fi}

\def\tp{\ifdim\cals@paddingT=0.0pt\relax    % Top padding switch (off-on)
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
\else \setlength{\cals@paddingT}{0pt}\fi}

\def\bp{\ifdim\cals@paddingB=0.0pt\relax    % Top padding switch (off-on)
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
\else \setlength{\cals@paddingB}{0pt}\fi}


\def\blue{\ifx\cals@bgcolor\empty     % "Switch" to turn on and off colour
    \def\cals@bgcolor{blue!5}
\else \def\cals@bgcolor{} \fi}


% R1H1
\thead{%
\brow
    \lp\cell{}\lp
    \alignR\cell{\vfil Diabetes}
    \alignR\cell{\vfil Hypertension}
    \alignR\cell{\vfil Heart failure}
    \alignR\cell{\vfil \textsc{copd} and Bronchiectasis}
    \alignR\cell{\vfil Asthma}
    \rp\alignR\cell{\vfil \bfseries Total(five conditions)}\rp
\erow
}
\tfoot{\lastrule\strut}
%R2B1
\brow
    \blue\lp\bb\alignL\cell{Admissions/discharges}\lp
    \alignR\cell{800\,303}
    \alignR\cell{655\,396}
    \alignR\cell{1\,749\,384}
    \alignR\cell{1\,109\,865}
    \alignR\cell{328\,976}
    \rp\alignR\cell{\textbf{4\,653\,924}}\rp\blue
\erow
%R3B2
\brow
    \lp\alignL\cell{\% of all admissions}\lp
    \alignR\cell{1.0\,\%}
    \alignR\cell{0.8\,\%}
    \alignR\cell{2.1\,\%}
    \alignR\cell{1.3\,\%}
    \alignR\cell{0.4\,\%}
    \rp\alignR\cell{\textbf{5.6\,\%}}\rp
\erow
%R4B3
\brow
    \blue\lp\alignL\cell{Average \textsc{los} (days)}\lp
    \alignR\cell{8.5}
    \alignR\cell{6.9}
    \alignR\cell{9.5}
    \alignR\cell{8.9}
    \alignR\cell{6.6}
    \rp\alignR\cell{\textbf{8.1} (avg.)}\rp\blue
\erow
%R5B4
\brow
    \lp\alignL\cell{Total bed days}\lp
    \alignR\cell{6\,794\,572}
    \alignR\cell{4\,597\,886}
    \alignR\cell{16\,619\,148}
    \alignR\cell{9\,855\,601}
    \alignR\cell{2\,177\,821}
    \rp\alignR\cell{\textbf{37\,603\,706}}\bb\rp
\erow
%R6B5
\brow
    \blue\lp\alignL\cell{Proportion of all bed days}\lp
    \alignR\cell{1.1\,\%}
    \alignR\cell{0.7\,\%}
    \alignR\cell{2.7\,\%}
    \alignR\cell{1.6\,\%}
    \alignR\cell{0.4\,\%}
    \rp\alignR\cell{\textbf{6.5\,\%}}\rp\blue
\erow\rmfamily
%R7N1
\brow
    \bp\lp\bb\nc{ltb}\lp
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \bp\lp\rp\nc{rtb}\alignL\sc{\emph{Note}: The data on hospital admissions refer to discharges (including deaths in hospital). They include patients in all age groups, but excludes outpatients and day cases (patients who do not stay overnight in hospital). The number of bed days was calculated by multiplying the number of admissions (discharges) by \textsc{alos}. The total number of admissions (discharges) excludes \mbox{healthy neonates.}}\rp\lp
\erow
%R8N2
\brow
    \tp\nc{ltb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
   \nc{rtb}\alignL\sc{\emph{Source}:  \textsc{oecd} Health Statistics, \url{https://doi.org/10.1787/health-data-en} and Eurostat database}
\erow
\makeatletter
\end{calstable}\par
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You like cals package :-). My upvote.

Comment: @Sebastiano The package solves some problems that are difficult to solve with existing packages, in particular coloured cells in combination with rules, and also vertical spanning of cells. Traditional, column based tabulars with lot of figures and without colour: tabularx, siunitx and booktabs have an edge. In my opinion, cals is a good supplement that people should know. And of course, building all this tabulars is a good exercise for me.

Comment: Meanwhile, I'm sorry I took the liberty of making a joke. Always good work and my best regards.